# How to setup an automatic redirect for when there has been a critical error on the site?

Tags: redirect, errors

Is it possible to automatically redirect to an external URL when the WordPress site has a critical error? Specifically when the site throws the "There has been a critical error on this website." error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [`WP_Fatal_Error_Handler` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_fatal_error_handler/) allows for a drop-in file to override the default handling of errors. If you have a file at `wp-content/php-error.php`, that file will be used instead of the default WP error handling.

Note that this drop-in file comes with some caveats:

> A drop-in `php-error.php` can be used as a custom template. This drop-in should control the HTTP status code and print the HTML markup indicating that a PHP error occurred. **Note that this drop-in may potentially be executed very early in the WordPress bootstrap process, so any core functions used that are not part of `wp-includes/load.php` should be checked for before being called.**

[emphasis added]

So you *should* be able to add `wp-content/php-error.php` with content something like this:

```
<?php
// wp_redirect() doesn't likely exist at this point,
// so we use PHP's `header()`.
header( 'Location: https://example.com/your-desired-url', true, 302 );
exit;
```

**Note:** The code above is *untested*.

### References

- [`WP_Fatal_Error_Handler`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_fatal_error_handler/)
- [`header()`](https://php.net/header)